# Spark scala: change numeric values in key-value pair to long/integer to join two maps

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, rdd, changetype

Hi I'm new to spark using scala. I have two different files, which I already created two maps as I need as follows:

```
data 1
1 : 2
2 : 1,3,4
3 : 2,4
4 : 2, 3
```

map1 will calculate the each key occurrence after the ":" The output for map1 is:

```
(1, 1)
(2, 3)
(3, 2)
(4, 2)
```

data 2:

```
apple
banana
kiwi
orange
strawberry
```

map2 will tell the element position and its output is:

```
(1, apple)
(2, banana)
(3, kiwi)
(4, orange)
(5, strawberry)
```

what I need is to join the two maps with output as follows:

```
(1, apple, 1)
(2, banana, 3)
(3, kiwi, 2)
(4, orange, 2)
(5, strawberry, 0)
```

I can only use org.apache.spark.SparkConf and org.apache.spark.SparkCotext. Here are the code I use so far:

```
    val sc = new SparkContext (conf)
    val data1 = sc.textFile("input.txt")
    val map1 = data1.map(x => x.split(":")(0), x.split(":")(1))).flatMap{case (y,z) => z.split("\\s+").map((y,_)}
.filter(_._2.nonEmpty).sortByKey().countByKey()
    val data2 = sc.textFile("input2.txt")
    val map2 = data2.zipWithIndex().map{ case(v, index) => (v,index + 1)}
.map(pair => pair.swap)

    val merge_map = map2.join(map1)
```

I want to join two maps that I have made but it throwing me an error like this:

```
type mismatch; 
found: scala.collection.Map[String, Long] 
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long,?)]
```

I was thinking maybe I need to change the type of the values in map1/map2. Any ideas how to do that? Thank you!

**FOLLOW UP QUESTIONS**:

Now I need to create map3 with the same data, which calculated the occurrence of each values on the right hand side after ":". And again join in with map 2. Here is the output of map3  and the join result I need of map3 and map2.

output map3:

```
(1,1)
(2,3)
(3,2)
(4,2)
```

join map2&map3:

```
(1, apple, 1)
(2, banana, 3)
(3, kiwi, 2)
(4, orange, 2)
(5, strawberry, 0)
```

Here is the code that I use:

```
val map3 = data1.map(x => x.split(":")(0).toLong, x.split(":")(1))).flatMap{case (y,z) => z.split("\\s+").map((_,1)}.reduceByKey(_+_)

val merge_map23 = map2.leftOuterJoin(map3)
```

I got an error :

```
type mismatch; 
    found: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String, Long] 
    required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long,?)]
```

I already fixed the previous code with the answers below, but now I got this error. Thank you

Comment: remote the `.collectAsMap`, while creating `map2`

Comment: @vdep if I removed the .collectAsMap it throwing me an error that said type mismatch; found: scala.collection.Map[String, Long] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long,?)]. Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `countByKey`. Use `reduceByKey`:

```
val map1 = data1.map(x => x.split(":")(0), x.split(":")(1)))
  .flatMap{case (y,z) => z.split("\\s+").map((y,_)}    
  .filter(_._2.nonEmpty).mapValues(_ => 1).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Then don't use `collectAsMap`:

```
val map2 = data2.zipWithIndex().map{ case(v, index) => (v,index + 1)}
  .map(pair => pair.swap)
```

Finally join

```
map1.join(map2)
```

Comment: it worked, thanks! May I know why it works when I use reduceByKey instead of countByKey?

Comment: I tried to do the same thing with my follow up questions (edited above) but it still throwing the error of type mismatch?